# html markup included in value component of json name-value -- proper way to display?

Tags: html, json, jquery-mobile

I have a json object that includes two straightforward name:value pairs and a third pair whose value includes html markup:

```
var sen = {
        train_cost: "900",
        plane_cost: "777",
        collapsible_content: "<div data-role='collapsible'><h3> A heading </h3><p>Stuff and more stuff, with some php variables, like {$this_var} and {$that_var}</p></div>"};
```

I'm trying to display `collapsible_content` as a jquery mobile collapsible, but the browser is ignoring the jqm markup (`<div data-role='collapsible'>`); as you can see in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/steveo_88/g8o0L1uf/2/) when you click on "senior." It recognizes the other html (the `<h3>` and `<p>` elements) and displays them, but I really want that jqm collapsible.

I've tried escaping the single quotes in the string that is the value part of `collapsible_content`, using backslashes and `&#39;`, but that has had no effect.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but it's not obvious to me. Any suggestions on how I could display that jqm collapsible?

Here is the html:

```
<form id='myForm'>
    <fieldset data-role='controlgroup' data-type='horizontal'>
        <label for='senior'>Senior</label>
        <input type='radio' name='switch' id='senior' value='sen' checked='checked'>
        <input type='radio' name='switch' id='student' value='stu'>
        <label for='student'>Student</label>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<table id="tab1">
    <tr>
        <th>Mode</th>
        <th>Miles</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Train</td>
        <td>3.9</td>
        <td class="view-train"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Plane</td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td class="view-plane"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class='collapsible_content'></div>
```

... and here is the js:

```
$('#myForm input').on('change', function () {
    var sen = {
        train_cost: "900",
        plane_cost: "777",
        collapsible_content: "<div data-role='collapsible'><h3> A heading </h3><p>Stuff and more stuff, with some php variables, like {$this_var} and {$that_var}</p></div>"
    };
    var stu = {
        train_cost: "5000",
        plane_cost: "8000"
    };
    var active = $('input[type="radio"]:checked', '#myForm').val();
    if (active == "sen") {
        $('#tab1 .view-train').text(sen.train_cost);
        $('#tab1 .view-plane').text(sen.plane_cost);
        $('.collapsible_content').html(sen.collapsible_content);
    } else if (active == "stu") {
        $('#tab1 .view-train').text(stu.train_cost);
        $('#tab1 .view-plane').text(stu.plane_cost);
    } else {
        alert('you selected nothing');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tell jQM to **[enhance](http://api.jquerymobile.com/enhanceWithin/)** the dynamically added content:

```
$('.collapsible_content').html(sen.collapsible_content).enhanceWithin();
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/f06vLtox/)**

Optionally you can initialize the collapsible instead:

```
$('.collapsible_content').html(sen.collapsible_content).find("[data-role='collapsible']").collapsible();
```

Comment: that works, thanks -- I had never heard of .enhanceWithin(). So if there were further markup nested inside of <div data-role='collapsible'> I should break them up into separate variables and do the same on the corresponding classes

Comment: @prokaryote, you can call enhanceWithin() on a parent container and all descendant controls will be enhanced.